# No "Blank Wear Activity" template shown for Android Wear on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, wear-os

I'm trying to set up Eclipse to develop for Android Wear by following this tutorial:

https://medium.com/@tangtungai/how-to-develop-and-package-android-wear-app-using-eclipse-ef1b34126a5d

I've made it to the step where one creates the new Android Wear Project and selects "Blank Wear Activity". On my setup, there is no "Blank Wear Activity" in the Create Activity dialog. It appears Eclipse is not finding the template to add to the list here.

I've tried this with Eclipse Luna downloaded from Eclipse.org, with ADT then installed via Eclipse's "Install New Software..." menu. I've also tried it on the pre-configured Eclipse Juno you can download from developer.android.com that has ADT pre-installed.

I can use the Android SDK manager to pull down the Android 4.4W platform stuff as well as Android Support Library and Google Support. I can find the wearable-1.0.0.aar and unpack it. I can import that project and all seems well. But I never wind up with the "Blank Wear Activity" template as an option. I've tried with and without installing the L Preview SDK.

All of this is on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the latest ADT (23.0.2), there isn't any wizard to create wear activity.
So you can try to download this Black Activity For Android Wear and start from there.

https://github.com/tangtungai/Android-Wear-Black-Activity-Template

Hope this help.

Comment: as far i know wear doesn't supports actionbar, even i made a sample project at that time i get to know that,then how your app is working with action bar?

Comment: also i want to know how to integrate the templete on above link in our app.i think its a normal activity. please reply ASAP. i am new to wear development.

Comment: and in your blog how your eclipse is showing blank wear activity option?

Comment: what the version of your ADT buddy?

Comment: Hi Dev, since the latest ADT 23.0.2, it wouldn't have the blank wear activity option. That's why you need to download this template. You can follow the steps show here: https://medium.com/@tangtungai/how-to-develop-and-package-android-wear-app-using-eclipse-ef1b34126a5d

Comment: i already follow your blog and also made a demo and its working fine,also many thanks for your blog.please countinue writting for android wear.

Answer (score 3):

The templates are provided by Android Studio, so you can't find it in SDK or your ADT.

You can find it in `AndroidStudio/plugins/android/lib/templates/activities`

Eclipse uses for its templates the folder `<android-sdk-folder>/extras/templates/`.
The language used is the same, but I don't know if they can works on Eclipse without changes.